# Repeat a menu and prompt if the user entered invalid choice in C

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement

```
void menu(){ 
printf("\n"); 
printf("1. Convert integers in decimal number system to binary numbers \n"); 
printf("2. Compute a consecutive square root expression \n"); 
printf("3. Solve a quadratic equation \n"); 
printf("4. Print something fun \n"); 
printf("q. Quit\n \n"); 
printf(" Enter your choice: ");
}
main () {   
char choice;
do { 
    menu();
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    switch (choice){ 
         case '1':
             ...
         case '2':
             ....
         case '3':
             ...
         case '4':
             ....
        default: 
            printf("Wrong choice. Please enter again: "); 
            break; 
    }

}
while (choice != 'q');
}
```

Here is my general idea, but I can't get it to prompt the wrong choice and repeat the menu. When I enter a wrong choice, the output is as follows:
For example, I entered 5:

```
  Enter your choice: 5
  Wrong choice, please enter again:
  1. Convert integers in decimal number system to binary numbers
  2. Compute a consecutive square root expression
  3. Solve a quadratic equation
  4. Print something fun
  q. Quit
  Enter your choice: (this is where I get to input)
```

Comment: Would you please include the output in your question?

Comment: I added the output, please take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below changes:
Change your scanf() as

```
scanf(" %c",&choice);
```

A space before the %c will make sure all special characters including newline is ignored.Without this everytime there is a newline in the buffer to and scanf reads from it and you will see that your look doesn't work as expected.

After this please make sure once the default case is hit you need to break from the while() loop.

```
    do {  
          menu();
          scanf(" %c", &choice);
          switch (choice){ 
             case '1':
                break;
             case '2':
                break;
             case '3':
                break;
             case '4':
                break;
             default:
               {   
                  printf("Wrong choice. Please enter again: "); 
                  break; 
               }   
          }   
   }   
   while (choice != 'q');
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, Put `break;` in each case so only the case you choose will apply. To solve the printing 2 times issue, just Change the %c in  `scanf("%c", &choice);` to %s >> `scanf("%s", &choice);`

This is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
void menu(){ 
printf("\n"); 
printf("1. Convert integers in decimal number system to binary numbers \n"); 
printf("2. Compute a consecutive square root expression \n"); 
printf("3. Solve a quadratic equation \n"); 
printf("4. Print something fun \n"); 
printf("q. Quit\n \n"); 
printf(" Enter your choice: ");
}
main () {   
    char choice;
    do { 
        menu();
        scanf("%s", &choice);
        switch (choice){ 
            case '1':
                printf("1 \n");
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("2 \n");
                break;
            case '3':
                printf("3 \n");
                break;
            case '4':
                printf("4 \n");
                break;
             case 'q': 
                break;
            default: 
                printf("Wrong choice. Please enter again: "); 
                break; 
        }

    }
    while (choice != 'q');
}
```

Comment: I already had    break;      in each case and changed %c to %s but it still gave the same output

Comment: i tested it with %s and it worked perfectly. i'll include my code in the answer.

Comment: @hzjw No need to use string here.